# portforward to Use two static IP for two webserver inside lan

Tags: networking, nginx, routes, cisco

My Static IP is provided by one ISP and network is:
 static1 IP:2.2.2.3 (test1.office.com)
 static2 IP:3.3.3.2 (test2.office.com)
router g0/0:static1
router fa0/0: 192.168.0.5 (LAN network)
webserver1: 192.168.0.10 (test1.office.com)
webserver2: 192.168.0.20 (test2.office.com)

Here what i have to do is i want to redirect both static IP to the respective webservers. I have already done this with **static1** but getting confuse for how to implement **static2**

**For Static1:**
I applied nat outside on g0/0 and nat inside on f0/0. NAT rules are:

```
ip nat inside source list 1 interface g0/0 overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.10 80 123.123.123.4 80  
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.10 443 123.123.123.4 443
```

But for **Static2** i am getting confused how to implement. Should i have to add another port g0/1 on router and assign Static2, and use one nat rule for the same or I have to work on different approach.  This should be accessible from outside internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need an Ip pool: 
ip nat pool pName addressRange (for your outside Ip addresses)
then
ip nat inside source list ACL_NO pool pName

Comment: can you explain more. remember i hv two static which has two different webservers and domain.

Comment: i tried another way. İ built a topology that like you explain up. With static NAT you can use just one router interface to go to the internet.

ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.10 1415 2.2.2.3 80 
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.20 1415 3.3.3.2 80

Comment: ok, m getting u little bit, but one of static IP 2.2.2.3 is used by router for default gw also and second static is not configured over router. So do i have to configure second static on the router free interface or directly i configure this over the reverse proxy server ? and if directly i configure this on reverse proxy server so how this server communicate with LAN network ????